# Is there a way to index list by the size of each element(integer)

Tags: arrays

say if you had a list that contains the element [5,7,83,1],
it would be stored as [2,3,4,1]
I want to do this in a single loop if you can; I need this to be very performant

Comment: what is the relation between [5,7,83,1] and [2,3,4,1] ?

Comment: which is the biggest in ascending order

Answer (score 0):

Here's an algorithm in Python:

```py
numbers = [5, 7, 83, 1]
ranks = {number: index+1 for (index, number) in enumerate(sorted(numbers))}
print([ranks[number] for number in numbers])
```

Explanation:

0. Start with:

   ```py
   >>> numbers = [5, 7, 83, 1]
   ```
1. Sort the numbers so you know what their "ranks" are: `5` is rank 2, `83` is rank 4, etc.

   - Cost: *O*(*n* log *n*).

   ```py
   >>> list(enumerate(sorted(numbers)))
   [(0, 1), (1, 5), (2, 7), (3, 83)]
   >>> [(number, index+1) for (index, number) in enumerate(sorted(numbers))]
   [(1, 1), (5, 2), (7, 3), (83, 4)]
   ```
2. Create a lookup table mapping each number to its rank:

   - Cost: *O*(*n*) amortized

   ```py
   >>> ranks = {number: index+1 for (index, number) in 
   enumerate(sorted(numbers))}
   >>> ranks
   {1: 1, 5: 2, 7: 3, 83: 4}
   ```
3. Construct the output list by looking up each number's rank in the lookup table:

   - Cost: *O*(*n*)

   ```py
   >>> [ranks[number] for number in numbers]
   [2, 3, 4, 1]
   ```

The total cost is *O*(*n* log *n* + *n* + *n*) = *O*(*n* log *n*).